# Bootstrap select dropdown showing selected option above the control

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

Not sure why the selected option is showing above the custom dropdown.  Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" />   
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/less.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <select>
            <!-- <option selected disabled>Select Name:</option> -->
            <option>Vogel</option>
            <option>Other Name</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
         <button id="btn_id" class="button-info">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.tinycolorpicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/offcanvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried defining a selected option (shown commented out) as well.  Doesn't matter what I put in the CSS, at least all the things I've tried, but this is what's currently running along with any Bootstrap 3.3.7 mods to the select.

```
select {
width:100%;
height:24px;
background-color:white;
border:2px solid black;
}
```

Actually haven't seen any other issues related to this exact issue, so I've been trying to hack my way through it.  Shows the same "bug" across browsers.  I am using a custom font for now, but I've tried to put a font-family change into the CSS above without luck.

Any ideas on how to get the option above the dropdown to go away?

**UPDATE:**
Here's the inspected column on Firefox:

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
  <div class="ui-select">
    <div id="select-27-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
        <span>Vogel</span>
        <select size="1">
            <option>Vogel</option>
            <option>Other name</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also added the js scripts at the end of the doc, including my custom main.js file that doesn't deal with anything  related.

Comment: Have you tried to put bootstrap's dropdown classes on the `select`?

Comment: I can`t see the problem in your code

Comment: Maybe it's an import, or some extra javascript... Have you inspected your code when selecting? Does it appear a new `<p>` or `<label>`?

Comment: @anfuca I updated the html code to include what's imported..I did inspect a while back, but I'll need to check again..brb!

Comment: @anfuca updated the post with the inspected html in Firefox

Comment: @whyoz Are you using any other scripts aside from what you've shown?  Such as [select2](https://select2.github.io/) or [selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)?

Comment: @Daedalus I was about to try selectize to try and override the issue, but yes, there are some js scripts at the end of the html doc I just included in the post

Comment: @Daedalus I just tried importing select2 and it did change the select control, but the selected option was still there on the same line to the left of the selector instead of on the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of those javascript is adding that `<span>`...
Try to guess who is or do this dirty trick: hide it with css

```
.ui-select span { 
  display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that, good eye.  This is similar to the fix I've been working on...I have a bunch of bootstrap overrides in style.less, so when I added this to the very end of the file, it did the trick!  Thx for the quick and easy hack!  I'm sure this style won't affect anything in the future (duh, duh, dunt!!)

Comment: I did confirm that it was the jquery.mobile.custom.js file that was causing the span to show above the select.  Since that file does way more good than bad, this still seems like the best fix for now.

Answer (score 1):

```css
select {
width:100%;
height:24px;
background-color:white;
border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.1/less.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css">
 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

 
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <select>
            <!-- <option selected disabled>Select Name:</option> -->
            <option>Vogel</option>
            <option>Other Name</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
         <button id="btn_id" class="button-info">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

this code completely have no problem we need to see rest of the code on your page to understand your problem

Update: the only file which i don't have online access to it

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less" />
```

without it code works well i think there is kind of mistake or style which effect your select

Comment: can you please inspect element and see what type of extra element you have ?

Comment: Updated the post with the inspected html in Firefox

Comment: check style.less as i update the code here we don't have problem until now mostly you have in style.less smth effect the select search on select there

Comment: the css in the post is from the style.less, which is essentially just a normal css